# Gridview CheckBoxList Checked State Not Holding When Clicking Edit - Complex DataBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with several BoundFields to a SQLDataSource (SelectCommand is a stored procedure).  DataSourceId and DataKeyNames are specified in the GridView (in the aspx page).  This works fine.  One column of the GridView is a TemplateField and EditItemTemplate with a CheckBoxList.  The DataSource (DataSet.Table[0] returned from a stored procedure), DataTextField, DataValueField, and DataBind() for the CheckBoxList is set in the code behind, in the GridView1_RowDataBound event.  This works fine also.  The initial Checked state of the CheckBoxList is set in the GridView1_RowDataBound event.  The Checked state is determined from records in a database table (a table named Modules_Platforms which links Module Ids, the DataKeyNames for the GridView, with Platform Ids, the DataValueField of the CheckBoxList).  The Checked state of the CheckBoxList is fine when the page loads, but when I click the Edit link in the GridView, all of the checkboxes in the row being edited lose their Checked state and are unchecked.  When I click Cancel, the correct Checked state returns and when I click Edit, select checkboxes and click Update, the correct Checked state displays.  I want the checkboxes to hold their Checked state when I click Edit, so the user doesn't have to remember those that were Checked and reselect them.

I should note that the CheckBoxList is not enabled when the page loads (not enabled in the ItemTemplate), but it is enabled in the EditItemTemplate.

I've searched and searched and not found anyone who has such a complex GridView with CheckBoxList that matches my example.  I put the same code in the GridView1_RowEditing() method that binds the CheckBoxList and sets the Checked value as I have in GridView1_RowDataBound(), and this didn't work.  I then put just the code to set the Checked state in the GridView1_RowEditing() and this also didn't work.  I also tried putting the GridView in Edit Mode in GridView1_RowEditing() prior to the code I show below, but that didn't work either.

The rows in the GridView display the Module names, and the text of each Item in the CheckBoxList displays the Platform name.  The Platform names are the same in each row, but the Checked state is based on the combination of the Module Id and Platform Id, and is read from the Modules_Platforms table, as explained in the first paragraph above.

I'm showing my GridView (aspx) code as well as the code for GridView1_RowDataBound() and GridView1_RowEditing().  Suggestions are much needed!  Thanks.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ModulesDataSource" DataKeyNames="MODULE_ID" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PageSize="50" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
<RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="False" ShowEditButton="True"/>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');"  CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Module Id" DataField="MODULE_ID" SortExpression="MODULE_ID"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Module Name" DataField="MODULE_NAME"  SortExpression="MODULE_NAME"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Key Designator" DataField="MODULE_DESIGNATOR" SortExpression="MODULE_DESIGNATOR"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Platforms">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblPlatforms" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Enabled="false">
             </asp:CheckBoxList> 
        </ItemTemplate> 
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblPlatforms" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">  
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ModulesDataSource" runat="server" OnUpdated="ModulesDataSource_Updated" ConnectionString="ConnectionStrings:ConnString" SelectCommand="GetModules" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="UpdateModule" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" DeleteCommand="DeleteModule" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure"> 
<DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="MODULE_ID" Type="Int32" Direction="Input"/>
    <asp:Parameter Direction="InputOutput" Name="Result" Type="Int32" />
</DeleteParameters>
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="MODULE_ID" Type="Int32" Direction="Input"/>
    <asp:Parameter Name="MODULE_NAME" Type="String" Direction="Input"/>
    <asp:Parameter Name="MODULE_DESIGNATOR" Type="String" Direction="Input"/>
    <asp:Parameter Direction="InputOutput" Name="Result" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        // Populate CheckBoxList controls from PLATFORM_MASTER table
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBoxList cblPlatforms = (CheckBoxList)e.Row.FindControl("cblPlatforms");
            DAL dal = new DAL();
            DataSet dsPlatforms = new DataSet();
            dsPlatforms = dal.GetPlatforms_Active();

            if (dsPlatforms != null)
            {
                if (dsPlatforms.Tables != null)
                {
                    if (dsPlatforms.Tables.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (dsPlatforms.Tables[0] != null)
                        {
                            if (dsPlatforms.Tables[0].Rows != null)
                            {
                                if (dsPlatforms.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    cblPlatforms.DataSource = dsPlatforms.Tables[0];
                                    cblPlatforms.DataTextField = "PLATFORM";
                                    cblPlatforms.DataValueField = "PLATFORM_ID";
                                    cblPlatforms.DataBind();
                                }
                            }  // end if (dsPlatforms.Tables[0].Rows != null)
                        }  // end if (dsPlatforms.Tables[0] != null)
                    }  // end if (dsPlatforms.Tables.Count > 0)
                }  // end if (dsPlatforms.Tables != null)
            }  // end if (dsPlatforms != null)
        }  // end if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

        // Display CheckBoxList controls status (checked / unchecked) from MODULES_PLATFORMS table
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBoxList cblPlatforms = (CheckBoxList)e.Row.FindControl("cblPlatforms");

            DAL dal= new DAL();
            DataSet dsModPlats = new DataSet();
            dsModPlats = dal.GetModules_Platforms();

            if (dsModPlats != null)
            {
                if (dsModPlats.Tables != null)
                {
                    if (dsModPlats.Tables.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (dsModPlats.Tables[0] != null)
                        {
                            if (dsModPlats.Tables[0].Rows != null)
                            {
                                if (dsModPlats.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < cblPlatforms.Items.Count; i++)
                                    {
                                        for (int j = 0; j < dsModPlats.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                                        {
                                            if (Convert.ToInt32(dsModPlats.Tables[0].Rows[j]["PLATFORM_ID"]) == Convert.ToInt32(cblPlatforms.Items[i].Value))
                                            {
                                                if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text != "")
                                                {
                                                    if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[2].Text) == Convert.ToInt32(dsModPlats.Tables[0].Rows[j]["MODULE_ID"]))
                                                    {
                                                        cblPlatforms.Items[i].Selected = true;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }  // end if (dsModPlats.Tables[0].Rows != null)
                        }  // end if (dsModPlats.Tables[0] != null)
                    }  // end if (dsModPlats.Tables.Count > 0)
                }  // end if (dsModPlats.Tables != null)
            }  // end if (dsModPlats != null)
        } // end if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBoxList cblPlatforms = ((CheckBoxList)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("cblPlatforms"));

        DAL dal= new DAL();
        DataSet dsModPlats = new DataSet();
        dsModPlats = dal.GetModules_Platforms();

        if (dsModPlats != null)
        {
            if (dsModPlats.Tables != null)
            {
                if (dsModPlats.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (dsModPlats.Tables[0] != null)
                    {
                        if (dsModPlats.Tables[0].Rows != null)
                        {
                            if (dsModPlats.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < cblPlatforms.Items.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    for (int j = 0; j < dsModPlats.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                                    {
                                        if (Convert.ToInt32(dsModPlats.Tables[0].Rows[j]["PLATFORM_ID"]) == Convert.ToInt32(cblPlatforms.Items[i].Value))
                                        {
                                            if (GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Text != "")
                                            {
                                                if (Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Text) == Convert.ToInt32(dsModPlats.Tables[0].Rows[j]["MODULE_ID"]))
                                                {
                                                    cblPlatforms.Items[i].Selected = true;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }  // end if (dsModPlats.Tables[0].Rows != null)
                    }  // end if (dsModPlats.Tables[0] != null)
                }  // end if (dsModPlats.Tables.Count > 0)
            }  // end if (dsModPlats.Tables != null)
        }  // end if (dsModPlats != null)
    }
```

Comment: When you click `Edit`, do you see the enabled CheckBoxes on the selected row or the disabled ones?

Comment: When I click Edit, the checkboxes are enabled and unselected on the selected row.

Comment: I never work with SqlDataSource in markup, so what I will suggest may not make sense. For testing, can you remove the `EditItemTemplate`, enable the CheckBoxes in your `ItemTemplate`, and comment out the code in the `RowEditing` event (except if you set the `EditIndex` of the GridView)? Would that allow you to edit/update your data? If so, there would be a way to enable/disable the CheckBoxes without the `EditItemTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ConnorsFan.  I did as you suggest and removed the EditItemTemplate, enabled the CheckBoxList in ItemTemplate, and commented out the code in RowEditing().  The result is exactly the same as before - the page loads correctly (checkboxes are correctly checked or unchecked) and when I click Edit, all of the checkboxes become unchecked.

Comment: When I edit data in a GridView, I essentially do 2 things in the `RowEditing` event: (1) set the `EditIndex` and (2) bind the whole data to the GridView (causing `RowDataBound` to be called). Did you try that?

Comment: I don't explicitly call GridView1.DataBind() in RowEditing but the RowDataBound event is called after I click the Edit link.  Sequence of events is 1) Click Edit link, 2) RowCreated (for all rows), 3) Page_Load, 4) RowEditing, 5) RowCreated (one row at a time), 6) RowDataBound (one row at a time).  I put in an explicit call to GridView1.DataBind() in RowEditing and it didn't change anything - still have the same issue of the checkboxes displaying as unchecked when I click Edit and showing the correct selections when the page initially loads.